# Generate trace templates in Emacs

Tags: emacs

While debugging, I usually write a lot of traces to print variables on screen during the execution. It would be nice if Emacs could write the template for me. I don't know how to program it on Emacs so I'm asking for your help :)

My idea is as follows. Something like M-x trace-template, that will ask for the name of a variable. Then, something like this will be added to the active buffer:

```
// trace20130604
cout << "test.cpp variable: " << variable << endl;
```

The date added in the comment allows performing a quick search for the day's traces to remove them when not needed. The "test.cpp" is the active buffer, automatically inserted. And "variable" is the variable's name that the Emacs command asks you when executed.

Do you think this would be useful? Easy to implement? Maybe already implemented? :)

Ideally, it should be mode-specific, so the right template could be inserted depending on the language you are using.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Regards.

## Solution for several major-modes

I've expanded Francesco's solution to cover for two major-modes. It's the first time I try to do something in Elisp and I suppose the code us ugly but it seems to work.

```
(defun trace-template (variable-name)
  (interactive "sVariable Name: ")
  (if (string-equal (format "%s" major-mode) "c++-mode")
      (progn
            (insert (format-time-string "// trace%Y%m%d\n"))
            (insert (format "cout << \"%s %s:\" << %s << endl;\n\n"
                  (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name)
                  variable-name variable-name)))
    )
  (if (string-equal (format "%s" major-mode) "fortran-mode")
      (progn
            (insert (format-time-string "! trace%Y%m%d\n"))
            (insert (format "WRITE(*,*) \"%s %s:\", %s\n\n"
                  (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name)
                  variable-name variable-name)))
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first solution would consist in using the [yasnippet](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet) extension, which aims at doing just what you need: inserting (potentially parameterized) templates into the current buffer.

Yasnippet is easily installable using emacs' packaging system, for example through the [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/) repository, and its [documentation](http://capitaomorte.github.io/yasnippet/) explains [how to write custom snippets](http://capitaomorte.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html). A snippet following your template could look like this:

```
#contributor : me <me@example.com>
#name : trace
# --
// `(format-time-string "%Y%m%d")`
cout << "`(file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name)` $1:" << $1 << endl;
```

Yasnippet can restrict snippets expansion to particular modes, so that I think you could easily define multiple language-specific snippets all named in the same way.

---

Another solution would be to write a custom Emacs LISP function such as the following:

```lisp
(defun trace-template (variable-name)
  (interactive "sVariable Name: ")
  (insert (format-time-string "// trace%Y%m%d\n"))
  (insert (format "cout << \"%s %s:\" << %s << endl"
                  (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name)
                  variable-name variable-name)))
```

Comment: Hi Francesco, thank you very much for your answer! I like your second function because I'm moving the .emacs among different computers so I only have to move one file.  I've been adding some ifs to print a different template depending on the major-mode. It took me some time but I think I did it :)